# Why YoungGen Size is different from Survivor Space after full GC

Tags: java, jvm

During a minor GC, objects still alived in Eden space and From (S1) survivor space are moved to the To (S2) survivor space, resulting in empty Eden and S1 spaces.

So it seems to be logical to have YoungGen size after minor GC equal S2 total size. But it's not the case according to the information reported by -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution JVM option's, which allows to print object ages in the survivor spaces in the GC Log.

**Q.** Why YoungGen Size after GC is different from the space (S2/To) as there is no more objects in the two others spaces in the Young Generation ?

The following two minor GC logs show the difference

```
2016-02-26T18:28:57.745+0200: 73803.862: [GC 73803.862: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 30507008 bytes, new threshold 2 (max 4)
- age   1:   19067112 bytes,   19067112 total
- age   2:   14083544 bytes,   33150656 total
- age   3:    5637688 bytes,   **38788344** total
: 526601K->**53312**K(536768K), 0.0139084 secs] 3828787K->3368267K(6231872K),      0.0140546 secs] [Times: user=0.44 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 

2016-02-26T18:29:08.151+0200: 73814.268: [GC 73814.268: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 30507008 bytes, new threshold 2 (max 4)
- age   1:   16633848 bytes,   16633848 total
- age   2:   16885136 bytes,   33518984 total
: 530496K->50445K(536768K), 0.0191598 secs] 3845451K>3382531K(6231872K),   0.0193089 secs]
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit :**
Just another example to illustrate the case where the survivor size's is under the desire survivor size, fixed by **-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio**, which shows that the survivor total size is different from the Young Size after GC too.

```
2016-05-26T08:00:16.348+0200: 36081.537: [GC 36081.537: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 30507008 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 4)
- age   1:   10236664 bytes,   10236664 total
- age   2:    9032760 bytes,   19269424 total
- age   3:    8856944 bytes,   28126368 total
: 527551K->46932K(536768K), 0.0101126 secs] 1644990K->1173951K(6231872K), 0.0102252 secs] [Times: user=0.44 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```